# Generating symmetric permutations

Tags: algorithm, permutation, pseudocode

I have a list of different combinations of letters of the alphabet

```
{{"a"}, {"b"}, {"c"}, {"a", "b"}, {"a", "c"}, {"b", "c"}}
```

There is no pattern to them - that isn't important to this problem. Let's call a permutation of this list **symmetric** if they are the same under substitution, i.e. you can get from one to the other by changing a to b and b to c, or b to a and a to b, etc. For example, the list above is symmetric to:

```
{{"b"}, {"a"}, {"c"}, {"b", "a"}, {"b", "c"}, {"a", "c"}}
```

Because you can get to the first from the second with `a=b`, `b=a`.

What I need to do is generate all permutations of a list which are *not* symmetric, to the original list or any other list in the set. I would like this algorithm to be as fast as possible.

I know about [Heap's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm) for generating permutations, and can quite easily generate permutations - but I feel like generating permutations and then looping over every element, and checking if it's symmetric to every other element is incredibly inefficient (**O**(n!)+**O**(n^2)).

What's the fastest way to do this? Or even any algorithm to accomplish it?

Comment: You should explain which permutations are symmetric. "Let's call a permutation of this list symmetric if you can get from one to the other by setting a=b b=c c=a or a=b b=a c=c etc. " is incomprehensible.

Comment: @user31264 Sorry! Permutations are symmetric if they are the same under substitution. Like if changing a to b in one permutation gives you another, those two are symmetric.

Comment: The worst case requires O(N!) time, as seen from `{{1}, {1,2}, {1,2,3}, {1,2,3,4}...}` (the only symmetric permutation here is the identity).

Comment: Please provide at least one example that has both input as well as the expected output.